# How to wait for list of tasks to complete in java and android?

Tags: java, android, task, wait

I want to do this while keeping animation and/or displaying texts about the current initialization process.
Once all tasks are completed I can enable certain buttons etc...
Since async task is deprecated I'd like to know what to use for that.